# PreparedStatement , CallableStatement and Performance Considerations

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a `oracle stored proc` that needs to be called from my Java program. I had used `CallableStatement` to pass parameters to the stored proc. I am using oracle thin driver (configured in web logic server against the relevant jndi entry).This stored proc does not have any OUT values. This stored proc accepts a numeric value and does a lot of updates in the db based on the value received.

I get a connection object and then call this stored proc in loop (20 times for passing 20 numbers). When I directly call this stored proc from an oracle client , the execution gets completed in 2-3 seconds. However the behaviour is not predictable from my java code. Some of the calls take even 30-40 seconds to get completed.

I tried to use `PreparedStatement` instead of `CallableStatement` and could see marginal performance improvement (though the behaviour is still inconsistent).

1. Is it OK in my case to use `PreparedStatement` instead of `CallableStatement` given that the storedproc does not have any OUT parameters?
2. Is there any reason why `PreparedStatement` has some performance gain over `CallableStatement` or is it something that I might have observed incorrectly?
3. Is there a better approach for solving this performance issue?

Comment: Can you post code? Alternatively, confirm that your connection isn't being established with each iteration (instead of using one connection repeatedly), and confirm that you aren't calling `conn.prepareCall()` with each iteration (instead of only having `.setInt()` and `.execute()` in the loop).

Comment: You call your stored procedure more than once, correct? Have you tried use batch calls? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/callablestatement.html   see 7.1.3

Comment: Instead of making 20 calls, why not try an anonymnous PL/SQL block (begin...call proc...call proc......end;) that calls your stored proc 20 times and make one call to the database with the anonymous block.

Comment: I am not allowed to work on the PL/SQL part of the program :-( There is a separate discussion going on to allow the stored proc to take a list of numbers as input. Sorry if I have understood your suggestion incorrectly.

Comment: You can create the anonymous PL/SQL block on the Java side: CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall ("begin foo(?); end;");

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your comment, you have prepareCall inside your loop. An advantage of prepared statements (and callable statements) is that you can prepare it once, and then swap out the values passed in the parameters; there is overhead each time the call is prepared, so if you could bring that outside of your loop, you may find that run time decreases. You may find that turning off AutoCommit also helps, as there is overhead with each commit.

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
while(true) {
    stmt.setInt(1, value);
    stmt.execute();
}
conn.commit();
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

(`conn.setAutoCommit(true)` does commit, but I find it clearer to be explicit).

Comment: Thanks Matt. I understand it a lot better I am sure this will fix my issue. I will try this and Sergio's suggestion. Appreciate your time and help :)

Comment: Hi Matt - tried both the approaches suggested by you and Sergio, but it still is slow when performed via my java code.

Comment: Update: I guess the procedure itself is very slow now , when I tried accessing the procedure directly using my oracle client - it takes about 2 minutes for each number. This behaves differently during different times of the day and it is something that I need to investigate. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Why not do a stored proc batch inserts then?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you consider using batch?

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
while(true) {
    stmt.setInt(1, value);
    stmt.addBatch();
}
stmt.executeBatch()
conn.commit();
```